# Registry Key Delete Error

Tags: registry

I created a registry key by program,

```
computer/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/test
```

But I can't manually (programmatically) delete that key while deleting through manually. I get this registry error message,

> cannot delete key: Error while deleting this key

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure from your question, but if you try to delete a key that has subkeys, it will fail. Check into [DeleteSubKeyTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3yfwzfx.aspx).

Comment: ...and in native code, you should use RegDeleteTree to delete a key that has subkeys.